# How to say restart the loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I didn't find the thing I need to do, so I'm asking for your help. I'm actually doing a loop that get all Docker machine, but sometimes for obscure reasons the machine are "undefined" and after a few moments they are running or stopped.

What I want to do is to put a thing in my code (I putted //here in the code) who stop all the loop and restart it.

```
getInfosMachines = Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(){
      //console.log("listener running");

      //clean the 2 arrays
      changeSpotted = false;
      stateLastCheckMachine.length = 0;
      stateDockerLastCheckMachine.length = 0;
      InfosMachines._ensureIndex({ "idMachine": 1});
          //add the collection value in the array
          InfosMachines.find().forEach(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(mch){
              stateLastCheckMachine.push(mch.stateMachine);
          }));
          //take the actual values
          Machine.list({ inspect: true },Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (err, machines){
            machines.forEach(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(machineInfo){
            if(typeof machines === "undefined"){
                sleep(2000);
                //here
            }else{
                stateDockerLastCheckMachine.push(machineInfo.state);
          }
      }));
}));
```

(yes there isn't all the code but it's here where I need some help)
Thank you for the help

[EDIT] Thank you to everybody who helped me, I learned from all of you !

Comment: There is no keyword or way to do it automatically. You need to do it yourself manually

Comment: If i'm interpreting your question correctly, you want to "wait" until all machines are defined? If that's the case, I would call [`machines.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) in a while loop until all machines are defined. Then after that, you can call `machines.forEach`.

Comment: yes but how to code something like this ? @Weedoze

Comment: @XåpplI'-I0llwlg'I- yes you are interpreting it right I'll try to code it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could "wait" for all machines to be defined with the following function:

```
function waitForDefinedMachines() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var machines = ...; // Get machines.

    if (typeof machines === "undefined") {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(waitForDefinedMachines());
      }, 1000); // Sleep for 1 second.
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  });
}
```

As you can see, it returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

And then call it like this:

```
waitForDefinedMachines().then(function() {
  // Do your forEach loop here.
});
```

(I stripped out the Meteor stuff from the code, since I have no experience with it. You'll have to add it back in, obviously.)

Comment: Arg the thing is that in the most of the case it's machines who isn't defined you have an idea how to wait until machines is defined ?

Comment: I'm testing it atm

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to control a loop is to use the basic for loop and manipulate the index.

```js
//Pseudo machines so we have something to work with
var machines = [10, 1, 4, 5, 24, 5, 8, 2];
for (var i = 0; i < machines.length; i++) {
  //Get machine
  var machine = machines[i];
  //Do something with it
  console.log("iteration", i, "looking at machine", machine);
  //Restart loop if parameter
  if (Math.random() > 0.8) {
    console.log("Restart");
    i = 0 - 1;
  }
}
```

A version with a build-in sleep until all machines are loaded:

```js
var machines = [10, , 4, , 24, 5, 8, 2];
//Wrapped in function so we can easily recall it
function testMachines() {
    //initial loop to test for undefined machines
    for (var i = 0; i < machines.length; i++) {
        if (typeof machines[i] == "undefined") {
            console.log("machine at index", i, "is undefined");
            setTimeout(testMachines, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
    console.log("All ready, running loop");
    //Pseudo machines so we have something to work with
    for (var i = 0; i < machines.length; i++) {
        //Get machine
        var machine = machines[i];
        //Do something with it
        console.log("iteration", i, "looking at machine", machine);
    }
}
//Loading the machines
setTimeout(function () {
    machines[1] = 99;
    setTimeout(function () {
        machines[3] = 98;
    }, 2000);
}, 2000);
//Start testing
testMachines();
```

Comment: It's not 100% what I'm trying to do, in my case it's `machine` who is undefined so I need to wait until it's not undefined

Comment: @Jerome That is correct, but there may be a problem. A loop eats nearly 100% of computing power, so everything will slow down a lot until the machine has loaded. You risk the browser thinking it to be "an infinite loop" and shutting down. An ideal solution would involve [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or some form of [sleep](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) delay between the loop tests.

Comment: Yes I added a method who wait Xsecond before each loop

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function

```
function checkMachines(machines,stateDockerLastCheckMachine){
  var stop=false;
  machines.forEach(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(machineInfo){
       if(stop){
         return;
       }
       if(typeof machines === "undefined"){
           sleep(2000);
           checkMachines(machines,stateDockerLastCheckMachine);
           stop=true;
       }else{
          stateDockerLastCheckMachine.push(machineInfo.state);
   })
}
```

Comment: Did you check also the other answer provided by @Emil? It seems better

Comment: Here the `checkMachines` func is called recuresively.. which could be heavy

Comment: Yes that why I'm back here ^^ I'll try to implement the one of @Emil

Answer (score 0):

You can simply decrease the index when the machine is undefined. It will check this machine until it is defined

```
for(let i=0;i<machines.length;i++){
    if(machines[i] === undefined){
        //Machine not started
        //Decrease index thus this machine will be check again next iteration
        i--;
    }else{
        //Machine has started. Do what you need with it
        stateDockerLastCheckMachine.push(machineInfo.state);
    }
}
```

If you want to wait 2 sec before checking the same machine again, you can add a wait function

```
function wait(ms){
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   var end = start;
   while(end < start + ms) {
     end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}

for(let i=0;i<machines.length;i++){
    if(machines[i] === undefined){
        wait(5000);
        i--;
    }else{
        stateDockerLastCheckMachine.push(machineInfo.state);
    }
}
```